# Basic Android Help?

Tags: android

SUPER FINAL LAST EDIT: i got it to work exactly how i wanted it to... and i think i learned something very valuable. First, i had to change the ID of the TextView (my old code said  r.id.usebuttonid. That is wrong. that referenced the button's text characteristic. i simply changed that and fixed a small problem with the string name for the TextView's ID String and it worked like a charm! Thank you all! i appreciate your input. The final code is below)

Final Code:

```
package com.jwright.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class testerproject extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.UseButtonID);
}

public void UseButtonOnClick(View view)
{
    final TextView joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.TextViewID);
    joke.setText("changed!");
    return;
}
```

}

---

Hello StackOverflow. I am new to android programming, but not new to java (i have to program in java for a class i take at my school) and am trying to learn the basics. I have looked through the "tutorials" on the developer site but cannot find them of any decent help.

I am simply trying to start small and work my way up. I want to slightly modify the basic program so that when i press a button, it changes the text to Changed!

i used the following code:

```
package com.jwright.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class testerproject extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.UseButtonID);
}

public void UseButtonOnClick(View view)
{
    final TextView joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.UseButtonID);
    joke.setText("changed!");
    return;
}
`}`
```

to create the button and try to change the text. Eclipse says it all checks out fine (no red marks, only some yellow ones) but when i run it on my phone (HTC EVO) and click the button (NOTE: it does work if i dont click the button... only once i click the button) it tells me that the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again.

if anyone could explain to me what i need to do to help you guys or if you can help me figure out my error, that would be great.!

Even better, if somebody knows of a free resource i could use that is much clearer and easier to understand than the developer tutorials, that would be great!

thank you very much in advance!

James

EDITED EDIT:
I figured out part of my error. I called the method the name of the string that i set the button's onclick value to, not the value of that string. problem 1: SOLVED.

HOWEVER! when the button was clicked... it changed the text on the button itself, not the textview's text. any ideas? The code above is changed to reflect the current working code.

Comment: How are you hooking up UserButtonMethod?  In the layout?  Maybe you have name wrong?  Please post that too if that is how you are doing it?  What you have shouldn't Force Close the, but wouldn't work either unless you are setting onClick in layout.

Comment: Is testerproject in your manifest.xml?  have you done just the simple 'hello world' in the developer tutorials?  there should be enough in the first 2 or three projects to get you to this point.

Comment: Basically you have to register an OnClick listener for the button.  The listener gets fired  when the button is pressed.  There you can have code to do whatever you want such as change the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it looks like you need to spend some time learning the basics. When I was first starting, these tutorials where incredibly helpful http://www.xtensivearts.com/topics/tutorials/page/2/

The Android developers documentation and tutorials can be pretty overwhelming at first but I highly suggest reading through as much of it as you can, even if you don't get it all and even if it is overwhelming.  Having a general sense of the terminology and framework that Android is built on will really help you as you move along.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html  Most of the articles in the Framework Topics category are really important to understand.

Although you asked for free resources, I also highly recommend [CommonsWare's books](http://commonsware.com/). They affordable and worth every penny.

In addition to learning how to build the apps, you should also learn how to debug them.  For example, you mentioned your app crashed. There are a lot of tools available to help you figure out why. LogCat spits out very specific information about why your app crashed so you can look there for answers. If you are using Eclipse you can see it from the Debug Perspective, or from clicking Window > ShowView > LogCat.  Some more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html

When your app crashes look at the log, you can filter it to warnings and errors only by clicking the W circle at the top of the LogCat.  It will have the stack trace for the error and you can follow it down to find where in your app it occurred and what line.

Comment: Thank you! i was looking through some other posts earlier and many people mentioned logcat and i had not a clue. I thank you very much for your input!

Comment: I should also mention that if you are asking about a crash and can provide an error log, it will greatly help your chances of getting a good answer since it will give people a lot more to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great link to help you on your studies: [Android-er](http://android-er.blogspot.com/).  I'm using it myself and am attempting to push whatever I do on my own blog (just started.)  I encourage you to do the same.  You never know who may see what you've done and give you some pointers.

Comment: ty! dang you are quick! i was expecting a bit of a wait before an answer. I shall have another look at the first android tutorials.